# categorizing short audio samples

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, voice, phoneme

I have a small number of similar types of sounds *(I shall refer to these as DB_sounds)* to which I need to match a recording *(Rec_sounds)*.  Each Rec_sound is  short and unique and needs to be matched to its corresponding DB_sound.  How do I go about matching them?

To illustrate my problem, consider the following:
Bob, with a deep voice in room A (with some background noise) says *Ma*
Alice, with high voice in room B says *Eh*
A Baby is learning to speak.  His first word is *Eh*

Ma and Eh are 2 different types of DB_sounds, so I have to return 2 different results.  I have several DB_sound samples of different people saying *Ma* and *Eh* to compare the Rec_sounds to

The sounds that I am dealing with are voice recordings of single syllables like *la, ba, ne, eh, ma* etc.

How should I tackle this?
I don't think audio fingerprinting will work (see spectrogram), and existing voice recognition software like [this google api integration in python](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) don't work since I am not trying to recognize human language, but just sounds.

I don't mind building something from the ground up, just point me in a direction you think will work, and please add plenty justification for why you think so.

**Spectrograms of 8 samples of a baby saying *EH***
[image]

**Time domain graphs of 8 samples of a baby saying *EH***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to recognize sounds, I would start with a simple procedure:

1. Crop silence from each sound sample (simple energy treshold).
2. Compute Audio Features for each sample of your database (e.g. [MFCCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)).
3. Perform a cross-validated classification procedure to map the audio features to the sound category you want to recognize.

Helpful Python Libs: [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) for reading wav files, [essentia](http://essentia.upf.edu/) for audio feature extraction, [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for classification and other machine learning.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar